# Gstreamer debug not working

Tags: linux, debugging, command-line, environment-variables, gstreamer

I'm trying to debug an linux application that uses gstreamer library 0.10 but I can't get the gstreamer logs to work. Here's what I tried so far:

```
export GST_DEBUG="*:6"

GST_DEBUG=*:6 ./app
```

I also tried to put the flag option in the pipeline creation:

```
gst_parse_launch("appsrc name=myappsrc ! alsasink --gst-debug=*:6", NULL);
```

`gst-launch` doesn't work either I tried:

```
GST_DEBUG=6 gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=out.opus ! oggdemux ! opusdec ! audioconvert ! alsasink
```

or

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=out.opus ! oggdemux ! opusdec ! audioconvert ! alsasink --gst-debug-level=6
```

I wasted a lot of time on this, some help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enable debugging for all elements :

```
gst-launch --gst-debug-level=5 videotestsrc ! autovideosink
```

enable debugging only for one element:

```
export GST_DEBUG=videoscale:5
gst-launch videotestsrc ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-gray, width=640,height=512 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```